# FlutterFire Auth verifyPhoneNumber method isn't being waited on

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create an auth service and I want to return the verificationId from the custom method. However, calling this method throws the null check exception because it doesn't wait for the Future to complete before returning.

```dart
Future<String> sendPhoneVerification({
    required String phoneNumber,
  }) async {
    String? result;
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+1$phoneNumber',
      verificationCompleted: (
        PhoneAuthCredential credential,
      ) {
        result = credential.verificationId;
      },
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          throw InvalidPhoneNumberAuthException();
        } else if (e.code == 'too-many-requests') {
          throw TooManyRequestsAuthException();
        } else {
          throw GenericAuthException();
        }
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, resendToken) {
        print('ver_id $verificationId');
        result = verificationId;
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (_) {},
    );
    print('This is the result $result');
    return result!;
  }
```

Here is the output in the terminal.

```
flutter: This is the result null
flutter: ver_id <ver_id>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I found out the verifyPhoneNumber method returns a future but the implementation doesn't await that async call. I used a `[completer][1]` to return a future.

```
Future<String> sendPhoneVerification({required String phoneNumber}) async {
    Completer<String> result = Completer();
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+1$phoneNumber',
      verificationCompleted: (
        PhoneAuthCredential credential,
      ) {
        result.complete(credential.verificationId);
      },
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          result.completeError(InvalidPhoneNumberAuthException());
        } else if (e.code == 'too-many-requests') {
          result.completeError(TooManyRequestsAuthException());
        } else {
          result.completeError(GenericAuthException());
        }
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, resendToken) {
        result.complete(verificationId);
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (_) {},
    );
    return result.future;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this property  `timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),` in the verifyPhoneNumber() method

Comment: I added it but it's still the same issue. The async method called isn't being awaited on and returns result as null. After the future completed, it then prints the verification code.

Comment: please remove "result.complete(credential.verificationId);" from verificationCompleted code. Now may be solve.